# res.redirect() unexpected behaviour

Tags: express

Both of these blocks of code redirect to `products/:id`. However, the path I have to introduce is different.

in the `post` route I have to include `products/`, but in the `put` route I don't.

Does anybody know why this is the case? Thank you for your time.

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const newProduct = new Product(req.body)
    await newProduct.save()
    console.log(newProduct)
    res.redirect(`products/${newProduct.id}`)
})
```

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body,
        {
            runValidators: true,
            new: true
        })
    console.log(req.body)
    res.redirect(`${product._id}`)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Redirections happen relative to the URL of the request that triggered them.

- The POST route is triggered by `POST /products`.
- The PUT route is triggered by `PUT /products/123`.

Relative evaluation effectively replaces the last segment of the triggering URL with the relative URL. This can be demonstrated with the `URL` class in Node.js:

```
> new URL("newid","http://server/products").href
'http://server/newid'
> new URL("products/newid","http://server/products").href
'http://server/products/newid'
> new URL("id","http://server/products/id").href
'http://server/products/id'
```